# Only one CSS rule is ignored for some pages

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've got a strange issue, on two different pages defined by the same stylesheet, one of the pages ignore a CSS rule. Here is the facts :

- My CSS file is loaded into both pages (veryfied with Firebug and native tool of Firefox)
- The property work for a page but not for the other, with the same code !!

Here is some screenshots to help understanding :
[image: Page 1]

For this one, the design is correctly applyed and I don't see any scrollbar on my iframe. But on this one :
[image: Page 2]
The design from "custom_design.css" is not showing up in the rules console when I select the iframe, since I applyed the design for both WPQ5 and WPQ4 id's ...

I post here a screenshot proving that my Page 2 has the same file linked (and if it were not the case, the Google form wouldn't have this style applied) :
[image]

Here is the whole style attached to my iframes :

```
/* this is the one not applyed */
iframe#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ5, iframe#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ4 { 
    overflow:hidden !important;
    min-height:55px;
    min-width:400px;
}

iframe {
    border: medium none;
}
.ms-webpart-chrome {
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
.ms-rte-wpbox {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 0px;
    line-height: normal;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    list-style: disc outside none;
}
.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.ms-rtestate-field TABLE, .ms-rtestate-write TABLE {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ms-rtestate-field {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
body, .ms-core-defaultFont, .js-callout-body {
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}
body, .ms-core-defaultFont, #pageStatusBar, .ms-status-msg, .js-callout-body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

If you want any other precision or informations about my problem, please ask me.
I hope it's clear enough, thanks for any hint :)

Comment: Can you paste your iframe's css please

Comment: I'm still stuck with this ... I don't get why this iframe# rule is uncalculated in one page ... since the css file is correctly loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found why it's behaving like this ... so I will at least post the answer.

The fact is : in the page where my Google search form got every CSS rules, the CSS file is included two times : one time into the iframe(in the head tag) and one time into the main page, that hosting the iframe.

On the second page, the .css file is registered into the iframe but not in the main page. So, it will only apply rules to the content of the iframe, but not the tag iframe itself. (considered as another page).

So I've added .css into the main page and ... all CSS rules were correctly applied. nice.
This is why you should avoid iframes, it's such a mess ... but I can't avoid it here since it's a widget from a particular CMS.

Answer (score 1):

In your Inspection View, switch from "Rules" to "Calculated" and search your attributes (overflow,min-height,...).

If the attribute is *not* present it means that your Rule in the stylesheet does not match - in that case check:

- stylesheet really loaded correctly?
- no selector errors (skips the rule)
- selector matches (HTML<->CSS)

  - in the inspektion view you have the possibility to right click the element and "copy unique selector" - use this one to apply your css-rules and try again

If the attribute is present, unfold it. Now you see the rule which actually applies to the element and where it originates. Check the source and take according actions:

- remove/adapt the rule (if it's in one of your own stylesheets)
- give your desired rule a higher precedence.

Comment: I checked in the Calculated tab and the attributes were not present. So I copied the unique identifier to be sure it hasn't a wrong character, but after a refresh there's no changes. And I'm sure the css file is loaded and applied to the page, because for instance, I can see the icon of the search button, which is a background attribute from this css. So it certainly the stylesheet not being read entierly... I'll go deeper.

Comment: Usefull advices, but no luck so far to make it works. I learnt that an absolute "position" would break the "overflow" attribute but there is no position attribute defined in the calculated tab of my iframe tag ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the second page doesn't have the stylesheet linked to it as I cannot see any rules from custom_design.css applied on it.

Could you please provide a link to both these pages, otherwise there is no way of telling what the issue actually is.

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide a link to pages because it's both hosted on a local server. But I can assure you the stylesheet "custom_design.css" is linked to the page. For 2 reasons :
1 - The form would not have this design if not
2 - Check the screenshot I will post